# Pong game in p5.js - background image not loading properly

Tags: javascript, p5.js

I'm using a javascript framework called p5. I'm trying to set the background of my Pong game to an image I found online. I followed all references I could find to try to get it to work, but for some reason the background doesn't update itself. I end up getting [a line of chickens](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EueIa.png) (the ball of my game). The only part of the background that seems to work properly is the top left corner.

```
var sticks = [];
var ball;
var wallDis = 50;
// var imgs = [];
var score = [];

function preload(){
    chick = loadImage('images/chick.png');
    farm = loadImage('images/Farm.jpg');
}

function setup(){
    createCanvas(600, 600);
    sticks[0] = new Stick([enter image description here][1]wallDis);
    sticks[1] = new Stick(width-wallDis);
    ball = new Ball(chick);
    score[0] = new ScoreBoard(width/3, 50);
    score[1] = new ScoreBoard(width*2/3, 50);
}

function draw(){
    background(farm);
    // resizeCanvas(img.width, img.height);
    for(var i =0; i<sticks.length; i++){
        sticks[i].move();
        sticks[i].show();
    }

    ball.move();
    ball.show();
    ... etc
```

Comment: Can you please post a [mcve]? We don't have to see any of your logic related to the game itself. Just show a sketch that loads an image and uses it as a background. Or better yet, post a link to a CodePen running your code. Have you checked the console for errors? Are those images located where you think they are? Where are you defining them? What exactly do you mean when you say the top-left corner is working?

Comment: There's an image at https://i.stack.imgur.com/EueIa.png 
The console doesn't have any errors. The images appear correctly, just the background doesn't seem to update/refresh with the rest of the game.

Comment: I went to make a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example for you and while I was doing that I figured out my problem. I had set imageMode(CENTER) which messed up the background. Everything works fine now. Thanks!

Comment: Hmmm, if that's really the case then that sounds like a bug. If you still have the MCVE you might consider filing a bug on the P5.js [GitHub](https://github.com/processing/p5.js).

Comment: Did you ever get this figured out?

Answer (score 1):

The `background()` function doesn't stretch the image to fit the size of the canvas. From [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/background), emphasis mine:

> p5.Image: image created with loadImage() or createImage(), to set as background (**must be same size as the sketch window**)

That's why you're seeing the image in the upper-left corner.

To fix your problem, just resize the image to be the same size as your sketch. You can do that ahead of time, or there are handy functions in [the reference](https://p5js.org/reference/) you could use as well.